# Reversible Debugger Exemple

Tags: debugging

I don't understend when the reversible debugger is better than an runtime debugger...
Someone can show me an example of code where a Reversible Debugger is better than a Debugger at runtime?

thx to all,
by 
Seba

Comment: Is this related to a specific programming language or are you looking for a general example?

Comment: a general example!

Comment: some idea for my question?

Comment: can you explain what is "reversible debugger"? Do you mean reverse debugger?